# Having problems pulling data from pokeapi

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the pokedex exercise and trying to make so that when showing the details of the selected pokemon I want to make every move that pokemon can have to have a background color depending of the type of the move.
For that I'm fetching the url of the selected pokemon, getting an array of every move and using foreach to fetch all those moves url's and get all their types , my problem is that their types are coming in their own separate arrays and when I try to access a position in the array it just shows the letter of each type that is in that position.

```
const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1`

fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    const movesUrl = data.moves.map((moves) => moves.move.url)
    movesUrl.forEach(url => {
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => data.type.name)
        .then((typeName) => console.log(typeName))
    });
})
```

With this I get every move type in its own separate array

```
const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1`

fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    const movesUrl = data.moves.map((moves) => moves.move.url)
    movesUrl.forEach(url => {
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => data.type.name)
        .then((typeName) => console.log(typeName[0]))
    });
})
```

And if I try to access a position on the array it just returns me the letter of each move type that corresponds to that position.

Comment: im guessing `data.type.name` is a string

Comment: What do you want to do with the type? Might be easier to make a object with all the moves and there info(type) and then use that to show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an array of the type names of each move.  That involves resolving a promise for each of the moves.  So, you can build an array of promises, and then handle their resolution with Promise.all.

```
const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1`

fetch(url)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    const movesUrl = data.moves.map((moves) => moves.move.url)
    const promises = movesUrl.map(url =>
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => data.type.name)
    );
    Promise.all(promises).then(result => console.log("array of move types", result));
})
```